# Compare two sheets then output differences - SEMI COMPLETED

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a macro that compares two sheets together and highlights the differences. Can someone please help me complete the next function where it outputs to a 3rd document with the differences already highlighted?

Column A contains a unique ID on both Sheet1(new) and Sheet2(old). currently Sheet1 will have new IDs highlighted in green, while changes in existing IDs will be highlighted in yellow wherever the change is.

I've been trying to add the next code where the highlighted differences become generated on 3rd sheet and shows the change but no luck.

Excuse me for my bad programming logic...

```
Sub Compare()

Compare Macro

Const ID_COL As Integer = 1 'ID is in this column
Const NUM_COLS As Integer = 120 'how many columns are being compared?

Dim shtNew As Excel.Worksheet, shtOld As Excel.Worksheet, shtChange As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rwNew As Range, rwOld As Range, f As Range, rwRes As Range

Dim x As Integer, Id
Dim valOld, valNew

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Change Report"

Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Change Type"
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ID"
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Name"
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Product"
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Range("E1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Old"
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Range("F1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "New"
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Range("G1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Difference"
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Columns("G:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Set shtNew = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set shtOld = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set shtChange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Change Report")


ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").AutoFilterMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Change Report").AutoFilterMode = False

Set rwNew = shtNew.Rows(2) 'first entry on "current" sheet
Set rwRes = shtChange.Rows(2)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").AutoFilterMode = False

Do While rwNew.Cells(ID_COL).Value <> "" 'Compares new Sheet to old Sheet

    rwRes.EntireRow(x).Value = rwNew.EntireRow(x).Value

    Id = rwNew.Cells(ID_COL).Value

    Set f = shtOld.UsedRange.Columns(ID_COL).Find(Id, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        Set rwOld = f.EntireRow

        For x = 1 To NUM_COLS
        r = 1

            If rwNew.Cells(x).Value <> rwOld.Cells(x).Value Then
                rwNew.Cells(x).Interior.Color = vbYellow

                'rwRes.Cells(r, 2).Value = rwNew.Cells(x, 1).Value 'ID
                'rwRes.Cells(r, 3).Value = rwNew.Cells(x, 11).Value 'Name
                'rwRes.Cells(r, 4).Value = rwNew.Cells(x, 12).Value 'Product
                'rwRes.Cells(r, 5).Value = rwOld.Cells(x, 14).Value 'Price old
                'rwRes.Cells(r, 6).Value = rwNew.Cells(x, 14).Value 'Price new
                'Percentage Change from old to new 'Difference

                r = r + 1
            Else
                rwNew.Cells(x).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            End If
        Next x

    Else
        rwNew.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen 'new entry
         'rwRes.Cells(r, x).Value = rwNew.Cells(x, 1).Value 
         'rwRes.Cells(r, 2).Value = rwNew.Cells(x, 1).Value 'ID
         'rwRes.Cells(r, 3).Value = rwNew.Cells(x, 11).Value 'Name
         'rwRes.Cells(r, 4).Value = rwNew.Cells(x, 12).Value 'Product
         'rwRes.Cells(r, 6).Value = rwNew.Cells(x, 14).Value 'Price

        r = r + 1

    End If


    Set rwNew = rwNew.Offset(1, 0) 'next row to compare

    Loop

   Selection.AutoFilter
MsgBox ("Complete")
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to copy rows with highlighted cells from `Sheet1` to Worksheets("Change Report"). Are all the highlighted cells in the *ID Column**?  You say there are 120 columns to compare?  But you only set 8 column headers.  Can you clarify this for me.

Comment: Hi Thomas, new IDs have the WHOLE row highlighted in green. While existing IDs have certain columns highlighted yellow. Theres 120 columns, but I only need to extract a few as these are the most important data. Thanks

Comment: I think that I get it. "Change Type" will be set based on the color, ("ID", "Name", "Product", "New") come from Sheet 1.  "Old","Difference" comes from Sheet 2. "Difference" is calculated?

Comment: Hi Thomas, that's right. Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I can see that the value comes from column 14, but what is the header?

Comment: That's a typo,14 should be PRICE. Therefore I should be able to see the difference between new price and old price in col 15.

Comment: Do you know how to make a class module and rename it?

Comment: Hi Thomas, yes. Thanks

Comment: Do we just need to check the color of cells in columns 1, 11, 12, and 14?

Comment: Hi Thomas, that's right. I only need these for now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to the solution posted by Thomas, you can make use of dictionaries to store indexes for each unique ID, and relevant columns. By population of the dictionaires in loops based on the hardcoded arrays (vHeader and vLookFor) and the range.find method, this enables you to change the position of columns and to some extent behaviour of the code without having to worry about indexes further down.

The script first populates up the dictionaries for header and ID's for the new and old sheets, and then loops the new ID keys to find the ones that had a change to any of the fields set as relevant in the vLookFor, and the ones that are brand new.

The use of the function columnLetter in the creation of the shtChange header range ensures that if you add a field to the vheader it will automatically be added to the shtChange.To avoid having to remove the shtChange in case you want to rerun the macro, I've added a doExist function - it simply deletes the sheet and returns a new worksheet object of the same name.

In case a difference, or a new field is identified, the line is moved to the shtChange and the difference calculated (New price/Old price in %).

Changing the order of columns would at the present wreck you field by field check for all 120 columns, but you could update this to use a dictionary, or more specifically range.find, mitigating the sort of stuff users tend to do (moving columns, sorting etc.) - but blame you for.

```
Sub Compare()
    'reference to Microsoft scripting runtime is a prerequisite for Dictionaries to work

    'can the shtOld.usedrange.columns.count potentially substitute this hardcode?
    Const ID_COL As Integer = 1 'ID is in this column
    Const NUM_COLS As Integer = 120 'how many columns are being compared

    Dim shtNew As Worksheet, shtOld As Worksheet, shtChange As Worksheet
    Dim vHeader As Variant
    Dim vLookFor As Variant
    Dim vElement As Variant
    Dim vKeyID As Variant
    Dim vKeyValueIdx As Variant
    Dim oldRowIdx As Variant
    Dim oldColIdx As Variant
    Dim newRowIdx As Variant
    Dim newColIdx As Variant
    Dim chgRowIdx As Long
    Dim oldPriceIdx As Long
    Dim newPriceIdx As Long
    Dim diffPriceIdx As Long
    Dim chgTypeIdx As Long
    Dim shtChangeName As String
    Dim oldIndexDict As Dictionary
    Dim oldIdRowDict As Dictionary
    Dim newIndexDict As Dictionary
    Dim newIdRowDict As Dictionary
    Dim chgIndexDict As Dictionary
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long, n As Long

    Dim x As Integer, Id
    Dim valOld, valNew

    'some intital parameters
    shtChangeName = "Change Report"

    'rather than printing the header one value at a time, then you can simply place an array directly into the range
    vHeader = Array("Change Type", "ID", "Name", "Product", "Old Price", "New Price", "Difference")

    'we create a array for the headers that we will be looking for, for the shtChange
    vLookFor = Array("ID", "Name", "Product", "Price")

    'setting the worksheet object
    Set shtNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set shtOld = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    'add the shtChange
    Set shtChange = doExist(shtChangeName) 'I really hate having to manually delete a worksheets in case I want to rerun, so I added the doExist function to delete the sheet if it allready exist

    'disable any data fitler
    shtNew.AutoFilterMode = False
    shtOld.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Generating the bold headers for the change sheet, to avoid retyping the range over and over again, we use with
    With shtChange.Range("A1:" & ColumnLetter(UBound(vHeader) + 1) & "1") 'this is implicitly repeated for all rows, e.g. '.value' -> 'shtChange.Range("A1:G1").value'
        .Value = vHeader
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

    'I will be using dictionaries to find my way around the position of specific headers and ID's. This I do for added robustness, in case the business decides to move columns, change the sorting etc. in only the old or new sheet
    Set oldIndexDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'for header index
    Set oldIdRowDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'for ID row index
    Set newIndexDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'for header index
    Set newIdRowDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'for ID row index
    Set chgIndexDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'for header index

    'we populate the index dictionaries
    For Each vElement In vLookFor
        If Not newIndexDict.Exists(CStr(vElement)) Then
            oldIndexDict.Add CStr(vElement), shtOld.Range("1:1").Find(what:=CStr(vElement), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
            newIndexDict.Add CStr(vElement), shtNew.Range("1:1").Find(what:=CStr(vElement), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
            On Error Resume Next
            chgIndexDict.Add CStr(vElement), shtChange.Range("1:1").Find(what:=CStr(vElement), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next

    'In case the data is not ordered exactly the same in the new and old sheets, we populate the IdRow dictionaries to enable us to find the position of a specific ID in either sheet
        'first the oldSht
        For i = 2 To shtOld.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'be aware that if your data does not start on row 1, the usedrange will not accurately reflect the true last row number
            If Not oldIdRowDict.Exists(CStr(shtOld.Cells(i, oldIndexDict("ID")))) And CStr(shtOld.Cells(i, oldIndexDict("ID"))) <> "" Then
                oldIdRowDict.Add CStr(shtOld.Cells(i, oldIndexDict("ID"))), i
            End If
        Next

        'then the newSht
        For j = 2 To shtNew.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'be aware that if your data does not start on row 1, the usedrange will not accurately reflect the true last row number
            If Not newIdRowDict.Exists(CStr(shtNew.Cells(j, newIndexDict("ID")))) And CStr(shtNew.Cells(j, newIndexDict("ID"))) <> "" Then
                newIdRowDict.Add CStr(shtNew.Cells(j, newIndexDict("ID"))), j
            End If
        Next

    'get indexes for fields specific for shtChange
    chgTypeIdx = shtChange.Range("1:1").Find(what:="Change Type", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column 'index for changetype
    oldPriceIdx = shtChange.Range("1:1").Find(what:="Old Price", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column 'index for old price
    newPriceIdx = shtChange.Range("1:1").Find(what:="New Price", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column 'indexd for new price
    diffPriceIdx = shtChange.Range("1:1").Find(what:="Difference", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column 'index for difference column

    'then we loop the keys in the New sheet and make the relevant comparision, incl. move to shtChange
    For Each vKeyID In newIdRowDict.Keys
        'retrieve the relevant indexes for the columns going into the shtChange
        newRowIdx = newIdRowDict(vKeyID)

        If oldIdRowDict.Exists(vKeyID) Then
            oldRowIdx = oldIdRowDict(vKeyID)

            For Each vKeyValueIdx In newIndexDict.Keys
                If shtOld.Cells(oldRowIdx, oldIndexDict(vKeyValueIdx)) <> shtNew.Cells(newRowIdx, newIndexDict(vKeyValueIdx)) Then
                    chgRowIdx = shtChange.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
                    shtChange.Cells(chgRowIdx, chgTypeIdx) = "Update" 'the key allready existed in the old sheet, so update

                    For m = LBound(vLookFor) To UBound(vLookFor)
                        If chgIndexDict.Exists(vLookFor(m)) Then
                            shtChange.Cells(chgRowIdx, chgIndexDict(vLookFor(m))) = shtNew.Cells(newRowIdx, newIndexDict(vLookFor(m)))
                        End If
                    Next

                    shtChange.Cells(chgRowIdx, oldPriceIdx) = shtOld.Cells(oldRowIdx, oldIndexDict("Price"))
                    shtChange.Cells(chgRowIdx, newPriceIdx) = shtNew.Cells(newRowIdx, newIndexDict("Price"))
                    shtChange.Cells(chgRowIdx, diffPriceIdx) = shtChange.Cells(chgRowIdx, newPriceIdx) / shtChange.Cells(chgRowIdx, oldPriceIdx)
                End If
            Next

            shtChange.Columns(diffPriceIdx).NumberFormat = "0.0%"

            'This is subject to risk of moved columns etc., but to retain functionality of the posted code we loop all columns the respective ID, and set the colors
            For k = 1 To NUM_COLS
                If shtOld.Cells(oldRowIdx, k).Value <> shtNew.Cells(newRowIdx, k).Value Then
                    shtNew.Cells(newRowIdx, k).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                Else
                    shtNew.Cells(newRowIdx, k).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                End If
            Next
        Else 'it is a new entry
            shtNew.Range("A" & newRowIdx).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen 'new entry
            chgRowIdx = shtChange.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

            For n = LBound(vLookFor) To UBound(vLookFor) 'loops the elements of the search fields, and if they exist in shtChange, we fetch the value from shtNew
                If chgIndexDict.Exists(vLookFor(n)) Then
                    shtChange.Cells(chgRowIdx, chgIndexDict(vLookFor(n))) = shtNew.Cells(newRowIdx, newIndexDict(vLookFor(n)))
                End If
            Next

            shtChange.Cells(chgRowIdx, chgTypeIdx) = "New" 'key is new, so New
            shtChange.Cells(chgRowIdx, newPriceIdx) = shtNew.Cells(newRowIdx, newIndexDict("Price")) 'since the element is new, only the new price is relevant for shtChange

        End If
    Next

    shtChange.Range("A1:G1").Columns.AutoFit
    shtChange.Range("A1").AutoFilter

    'set the dicts to nothing
    Set oldIndexDict = Nothing
    Set oldIdRowDict = Nothing
    Set newIndexDict = Nothing
    Set newIdRowDict = Nothing
    Set chgIndexDict = Nothing

    MsgBox ("Complete")
End Sub



Function doExist(strSheetName) As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsTest As Worksheet
    Dim nWs As Worksheet

    Set wsTest = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsTest = wb.Worksheets(strSheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not wsTest Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wsTest.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    Set doExist = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    doExist.Name = strSheetName

End Function


Function ColumnLetter(ColumnNumber As Long) As String
    Dim n As Long
    Dim c As Byte
    Dim s As String

    n = ColumnNumber
    Do
        c = ((n - 1) Mod 26)
        s = Chr(c + 65) & s
        n = (n - c) \ 26
    Loop While n > 0
    ColumnLetter = s
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, this works. just wondering if I wanted to add another column to detect change that's not a a number, eg. Current > Discontinued is it possible to add it in the "Difference"?

Comment: that depends what difference we are then talking about. If it is still price, then it is allready in effect, else it would require a little manipulation, but could be done

Comment: Hi Andreas, thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it as well. I'm going to tweak it more to compare other columns. However I have to format all cells and change it to 'Text' for it to work and sometimes I get duplicate results, do you know why?

Comment: not at the face of it no, and I would likely neeed some actual data to recreate such an issue. The small sample data I made for myself does not exibit the described issues, so I am not quite sure where your issue resides. Are you familiar with breakpoints, the Locals and Immediate window?

Comment: Hi Andreas, all working now, I just used removed duplicates as a quick fix, but the duplicates seem to appear when I added more columns to import(price change, supplier change, etc) I've saved both solutions and this has definitely helped me. I really appreciate it :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to set a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

This should be really close to what you want.

- ProductRecord: Stores all the variable to be written to the new worksheet
- dProducts: Is a dictionary that holds the ProductRecords
- Iterate Sheet1 adding products to dProducts by ID if there they cells are colored
- Iterate Sheet2 searching for dProducts by ID. If found we set the product's Old Price
- Iterate Worksheet("Change Report") Pasting the products in dProducts as we go

**Class ProductRecord**

```
Option Explicit

Public ChangeType As String
Public ID As String
Public Name As String
Public Product As String
Public OldPrice As Double
Public NewPrice As Double
Public Difference As Double
Public Color As Long

Public Sub Paste(Destination As Range)
    Dim arData(5)
    Difference = NewPrice - OldPrice
    If Color = vbGreen Then ChangeType = "New Product" Else ChangeType = "ID Change"
    arData(0) = ChangeType
    arData(1) = Name
    arData(2) = Product
    arData(3) = OldPrice
    arData(4) = NewPrice
    arData(5) = Difference

    Destination.Resize(1, 6) = arData 'WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arData)
    Destination.Interior.Color = Color

End Sub
```

**The rest of the story**

Option Explicit

```
Sub Compare()
    ToggleEvents False
    Dim shtNew As Excel.Worksheet, shtOld As Excel.Worksheet, shtChange As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rwNew As Range
    Dim k As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long, y
    Dim Product As ProductRecord
    Dim dProducts As Dictionary
    Set dProducts = New Dictionary

    Set shtNew = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set shtOld = Sheets("Sheet2")

    shtNew.AutoFilterMode = False
    shtOld.AutoFilterMode = False

    With shtNew
        lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 2 To lastRow
            For Each y In Array(1, 11, 12, 14)
                If .Cells(x, y).Interior.color = vbYellow Or .Cells(x, y).Interior.color = vbGreen Then
                    Set Product = New ProductRecord
                    k = .Cells(x, 1).Value
                    Product.color = .Cells(x, y).Interior.color
                    Product.ID = .Cells(x, 1).Value    'ID
                    Product.Name = .Cells(x, 11).Value    'Name
                    Product.Product = .Cells(x, 12).Value    'Product
                    Product.NewPrice = .Cells(x, 14).Value    'Price old

                    If Not dProducts.Exists(k) Then
                        dProducts.Add k, Product
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With

    If dProducts.Count > 0 Then
        With shtOld
            lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            For x = 2 To lastRow
                k = .Cells(x, 1).Value

                If dProducts.Exists(k) Then

                     dProducts(k).OldPrice = .Cells(x, 14).Value    'ID

                End If
            Next

        End With
    End If

    Set shtChange = getChangeReportWorkSheet

    With shtChange.Range("A1:G1")
        .Value = Array("Change Type", "ID", "Name", "Product", "Old", "New", "Difference")
        Selection.Font.Bold = True
    End With

    With shtChange
        lastRow = dProducts.Count - 1
        For x = 0 To lastRow

            dProducts.Items(x).Paste .Cells(x + 2, 1)

        Next
        .Range("A1:G1").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

    ToggleEvents True
    'Selection.AutoFilter
    MsgBox ("Complete")
End Sub

Sub ToggleEvents(EnableEvents As Boolean)

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = EnableEvents
        .Calculation = IIf(EnableEvents, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    End With

End Sub

Function getChangeReportWorkSheet() As Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Change Report").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set getChangeReportWorkSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    getChangeReportWorkSheet.Name = "Change Report"
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, I think I've done something wrong. When I hit run it shows "invalid outside procedure" pointing to 'Class ProductRecord' I've also added MS Scripting Runtime. Thanks

Comment: That was my fault I thought fixed it in the post.  For some reason if when I declare `dProducts as Dictionary` I am not able to add my custom class to it.  Strangely enough, by use delaring it as a variant and using `CreateObject` I don't get that message. `Set dProducts = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`

Comment: Hi Thomas, still not good, I'm suppose to put it right at the top right? But for the time being I'll use Andreas code. But thank you so much for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have ProductRecord in a class module?

Comment: Hi Thomas, sorry I'm such an idiot forgot to rename class to ProductRecord.  I now have Run-time error 451 - Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object. for "Set Product = dProducts.Items(1)"

Comment: @John T I was mistaken you do need to set a reference to the **Microsoft Scripting Runtime**.  I refined my test stub and tweaked the code it should run fine for you now.  New feature will delete the old report if it exists.  This will allow you to run `Compare()` multiple time.  [Download My Test Stub](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fx3cn4xkhbwy4p2/PriceCompare.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: Hi John, thank you so much, works perfectly now. I really appreciate it :)